# Referencing to an agent from experiment

Tags: anylogic

I have an experiment page and a few agents in my model. At the "Before simulation run" properties of the experiment, I have to read some parameters off an agent (e.g. the agent is called Equipment) which is not the main, hence i can't use root.XXX to access the parameters. How can I refer to the an object inside Equipment from the experiment page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to navigate through the model hierarchy.

- If `Equipment` is embedded in `Main`, you use `root.equipment`
- If `Equipment` is embedded in `Machine` which is embedded in `Main`, you use `root.machine.equipment`

If your agents are actually populations, the code changes to `root.equipmentPop.get(x)`

See this help article to learn more: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Comment: You also need to make sure those agents have been instantiated.  The nice thing about putting code at the experiment level is you can get variables set and functions called before the model runs.  The flip side is that those agents you want to reason with may not exist yet.

Comment: 100% true, thx Amy :)